# how to query array to specific index in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data in MongoDB like this

```
{      
     attribute0
     attribute1
     address:
          [0] :  some data1
          [1] :  some data2
}
```

the address is of an Array type in MongoDB, and I am using the "address" as sort of a map where a certain value should always go to the index 0, and "1" is the same, for simplicity of the example, let say,
if its an email, index 0: is always the receiver, and 1 is the sender.

when I do query conditions like

```
collection.find ({'meta.addresses[0]': 'some data1'});
```

I'm not getting any result

so I tried just to do

```
collection.find ({'meta.addresses': 'some data1'});
```

And instead, I got result. But this is not what I want since if the "somedata1" value is in index 1, it will still return the result, which is wrong.

How do I do this? I mean query an array element for a certain value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dot notation. Try this:

```
collection.find({'meta.addresses.0': 'some data1'});
```